# Is there a test for convexity?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, computability

This is a very heterodox question. But here is the context. I'm programming a computational package, and the user may write/define a cost function freely, e.g.
$$
cost(x,y) = e^{|x-y|} (x-y)^2.
$$
Now, the algorithm programmed only works if the cost function is convex. Here is where my question comes in. Would there be some kind of test to verify if the function is indeed convex? Mathematically, we can try to manipulate the function in order to verify whether it satisfies the convexity definition, but this scenario does not allow for such approaches.
I was thinking for something like "sample some points, calculate the function and verify if the mid point is above the linear interpolation". How many points would be necessary to correctly guess that the function is convex with a certain probability? Any references on this kind of odd question (the probability that a function is convex)?

Comment: I really like the probabalistic approach to the question, although I'm not aware of any result guaranteeing this. One problem is that, unless your cost function is restricted to a bounded domain, it's hard to "evenly" sample an unbounded domain with a finite-time algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, as part of the question (although I forgot to mention) would be to somehow evaluate some sort of local invariance behavior of a function.

Comment: If your cost function is twice-differentiable in all directions, another necessary (but insufficient) way to check convexity would be to test that the Jacobian is positive-semidefinite at your sample points. The problem with computationally verifying convexity is that we only get information about the function locally near those sample-points. However, the cost function could still be nonconvex in some other unknown region.

Comment: How do you know that such a probability exists? Remember that probability is not a vague notion. You need to define a space and a measure on it. How do you associate to a function a probability?

Comment: The problem I'm tackling is Optimal Transport between measures. Now, if the measures have infinite support, then yeah, I'm in trouble. But in many cases, my distributions are actually samples, so they have a compact support. Thus, I would only need to check convexity locally.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net , that would be part of the question, hehe. I mean, I was wondering if there was something out there. Like, for a given function in a compact support, I can easily think of a programmable processes where the probability indeed exists.

Comment: @DaviBarreira Can you outline for us this programming process… There is a countable infinite number of continuous maps defined on a compact by a program. How do you associate a probability to each of those? Such a probability can’t be different of zero if all functions have the same probability , otherwise the probability of the whole space would be infinite…. And if the probabilities are different, how do you give more weight to some functions? This argument is almost proving that such a probability doesn’t exist.

Comment: Of course, for any function things can become messy. But perhaps assuming continuity and some smoothness, there is a way to define some sort of robust test.

Comment: But this specific test is just something I came up with. I'm happy if someone can come up with something different and which can be indeed proved to exist. :)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net , I guess you are right. It's not that simple. I was thinking of something like, take the function such as $c(x,y) = h(y-x) = (x-y)^2$, and suppose we are only interested if this function is convex between 0 and 1. Then, I'd sample points using a uniform distribution, and do the process outlined. Now, since this function is convex, then all good, the test would always pass. Now suppose instead that my function is the sigmoid. It would seem that again the probability would exists, and it would be 1/2 in this case (maybe).

Answer (score 1):

**Heuristic argument to prove that such a probability can’t be defined in a meaningful way.**

Let $\Omega$ be the set of maps that can be defined with a program. $\Omega$ is countable infinite. Therefore if $K \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a compact, the subset $\Omega_K \subseteq \Omega$ of continuous maps defined on $K$ is also countable.

Now, to get a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space?wprov=sfti1) $(\Omega_K, \mathcal A, P)$ on $\Omega_K$, we have to define a probability function $P$ on $\Omega_K$. $P$ can’t be constant and different of zero as otherwise the probability of the whole space $\Omega_K$ would be infinite. $P$ can’t either be equal to zero.

Therefore $P$ has to be non constant. You could attach a probability that would depend on the length of the program that defines the function or something similar (and the probability decreases to zero as the length of the program increases)… but then the probability for convexity will depend on your programming language!

Not saying that it is impossible. But rather that it would be rather meaningless.

*Then assuming that such a (meaningless) probability has been defined, you raised a second point, about the number of sampling points required to test convexity. You’ll enter here other difficulties. I.e. that the answer depends on the chosen points, and nice topics like that.*

Comment: Is your argument related to the space of functions? Because I'm not actually trying to compute the probability of selecting a function that is convex, but in creating a sampling process and finding the probability that such test returns to me that the function is convex, when, for example, the function is not.

Comment: In my mind, if I restrict the set of possible functions to, let's say, continuous functions defined on a compact space. Now, suppose that this function is convex. Then my test will always fail, i.e. it will never say that the function is not convex when it is convex. But if the function is something like a sigmoid, then I know that half of it is convex, while the other half is not. So I'm guessing that my test will fail if the mid-point of the two samples falls in the concave region, which will happen with $P = 1/2$. Does this make sense?

Comment: I do agree that your test won’t be conclusive for a continuous convex map. I’m likely to agree for a probablity of $1/2$ in the case of the sigmoid (I say likely as a detailed computation process is required ). But then you not only know that your function is not convex. You know that it is a **very specific** non convex map. What will you do to get such a probability for any non convex map? Wouldn’t you need to use the [total law of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability?wprov=sfti1)? In that case you’re back to my first point. What will you do otherwise?